# TabLayout tabs randomly displaying only 2 characters in each title

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have an activity containing a TabLayout with tabMode set to 'scrollable':

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/white">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_gravity="bottom" app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Most of the time, the TabLayout displays correctly and shows the entire title text for each tab, like this:

[image: TabLayout without any issues]

Sometimes, however, it displays only the first two characters from the title, like this:

[image: TabLayout with issue showing]

During the activity's creation, I am calling:

```
setSupportActionBar(getToolbar());
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Within my fragment, which is being rendered in my activity, I am initializing the TabLayout as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, null);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.removeAllTabs();
        tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
        return view;
    }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new PeopleFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The FragmentAdapter code looks like this:

```
public class PeopleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PeopleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PeopleFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Nearby";
            case 1:
                return "Online";
            default:
                return "Following";
        }
    }
}
```

The PeopleFragment which is hosted inside the first fragment, created an options menu from an XML file:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 0) < 2)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_people, menu);
}
```

The reason the TabLayout is in the activity's layout rather than the first fragment, is because it is being re-used by other fragments which are accessible via a BottomBar.

Strangely, and possibly not relevant, when I took a screenshot of the device while it was exhibiting the issue, the height was substantially greater than usual (as you can see in the screenshot above).

What might be causing the TabLayout to truncate the the titles?  Is the extra tall screenshot being created somehow related?

Comment: show more code, Java especially, not only XML. you are clearly manipulating with `Toolbar` by code, you don`t have filter menu icon inside XML (is present on first screenshot and not on present on second "broken" one)

Comment: I edited my question to include the relevant code.  I'm not doing much though.